# Get geographic coordinate system for its projected coordinate system in ArcObjects.NET

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.3

I have geometry in PCS, that must be convert to GCS, while PCS is projection of GCS.

How can I get `ISpatialReference` for PCS's parent using ArcObjects.NET?

Comment: am I correct: you don't know your target spatial reference but want to derive it somehow from your geometry's spatial reference?

Comment: I know projected coordinate system and want to convert geometry to its geographical coordinate system. Known PCS is projection of GCS that I want to get. In Python I can get export spatial reference to string, extract ```GEOGCS[...``` and create parent geographical CS, but what about AcrObjects.NET?

Comment: IProjectedCoordinateSystem:GeographicCoordinateSystem. You should be able to do something similar in ArcPy: GCS is a property of SpatialReference.

Comment: ArcObjects Java it's [IProjectedCoordinateSystem.getGeographicCoordinateSystem()](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-java/api/arcobjects/com/esri/arcgis/geometry/IProjectedCoordinateSystem.html#getGeographicCoordinateSystem%28%29)